# Lua Table Value to Variable after reciving Text message

Tags: lua

```
local table =
{
one = {"one", "two", "three"},
two = {"four", "five", "six"},
three = {"seven", "eight", "nine"},
}
```

Iam reciving a string data that contains one of the word's in table above. 
I want to put that suitable word into a variable lets say 'x'.

So lets say one of the message is random and generated this time : "This is the day one and its windy". I wish to store "one" into a variable x. But after reciving "Now its day two and its sunny" I wish x to be two. Also after getting that variable set I need to precise from which table it was taken "one" "two" or "three".

Comment: So in other words, you need to store two values, not just the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I undestand correcty what do you need, but check this function.

```
local table =
{
one = {"one", "two", "three"},
two = {"four", "five", "six"},
three = {"seven", "eight", "nine"},
}


local x = nil
local tab = nil
local sentence_1 = 'Now its day six and its sunny'
local sentence_2 = 'Now its day two and its sunny'


function search_word(sentence, words_table)  
  for key, words in pairs(words_table) do
      for _, word in pairs(words) do
          if string.match(sentence, word) then
            return word, key
          end
      end
  end    
end

x, tab = search_word(sentence_1, table)

print(x, tab)
-- six  two

x, tab = search_word(sentence_2, table)

print(x, tab)
-- two  one
```

`search_word` function takes two arguments: sentence and your table with words, and function returns two values - first one is the word that was found and second  is the table that contained this word .

Comment: `break` exits only inner `for`, not both.  Probably, `return` suits better in this situation.

Comment: thank you very much, I made the code before you gave me the answer but it took 100 line's. I need to get better in loop inside loop. Can you point me to good documentary about this?. Thanks again

Comment: @OskarGarczyński , I mainly use the official Lua documentation (https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/) and the lua-users page (http://lua-users.org/wiki/).  the best exercise for understanding nested loops is write one, and add some `print` inside these loops. in the above function you can add print(key, word) inside first loop. you can change second loop to`for k, word in pairs(words) do`, and replace if statement by print(k, word). in this way, you will understand best how two loops iterate over your table.